# Trouble publishing Azure web application with an SQL DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, deployment, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to publish my web application on Azure with a SQL server for the data. I can deploy the application without error when I don't select the "*Execute Code First Migrations (Runs on application start)*"

When deployed without this option selected however I don't have my database associated functionality such as seeded content or login/register.

When selecting this option (as recommended) I get this error which doesn't tell me much: *The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.*

Update:
I have checked the Azure SQL database and all of the correct tables are there apart from the seeded data. I enabled application insights on Azure. It came up with the following problem now: *There is an issue with your web.config. One of the configuration sections in your config cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.*

Comment: do you have a .debug and a .release web config? sometimes when you deploy it publishes the release one and combines the two configs and causes issues.

Comment: I have Web.Config and under this I have Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config

Comment: comment out the .debug and .release and try clean/publishing again

Comment: still no luck, spent a long time with this now trying different solutions

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a new project (not ideal). While choosing the options I selected to host in the cloud and then moved files over etc. This worked in the end